# Custom Rounded Button without Corner Radius

Tags: ios, custom-controls, calayer

how do we subclass a UIbutton and customize it so that it has a round end like this one on Periscope. The Following Button.

I would like to **PREVENT** using **layer.CornerRadius though**.

Using a BezierPath perhaps? but I have a math problem creating the Path.

Any thoughts? Thank you

[image: rounded following button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created that button using the layer.CornerRadius as below :-

```
self.buyButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.buyButton.frame.size.height/2;
self.buyButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

[UPDATED CODE - FOR SHADOW]

```
self.buyButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

self.buyButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;    //Just for look n feel

self.buyButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
self.buyButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
self.buyButton.layer.shadowRadius = 12;
self.buyButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(12.0f, 12.0f);
```

[image]

But why u don't want to use the method already provided as per your custom requirement I don't think you need to use bezier path for this.

UPDATED SCREENSHOT :

[image]

Comment: cause if I use the Layer.cornerRadius method, I am not gonna be able to add shadow to it anymore.